# Getting an error Timeout::Error: Timeout::Error with Firefox using Watir-webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

I want to run my scripts using firefox 17 but then it launches correctly but fails to navigate completely. 
It results in a `Timeout::Error: Timeout::Error`. 
I do NOT see this error with chrome or IE.
Using JRuby 1.7.12, Watir-Webdriver 0.6.10 selenium-webdriver 2.42.0

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new 'firefox'
b.goto 'bit.ly/watir-webdriver-demo'
b.text_field(:id => 'entry_0').set 'your name'
```

Error message

```
Timeout::Error: Timeout::Error
from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/1.9/net/protocol.rb:146:in `rbuf_fill'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/1.9/net/protocol.rb:122:in `readuntil'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/1.9/net/protocol.rb:132:in `readline'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:2570:in `read_status_line'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:2559:in `read_new'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:1327:in `transport_request'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1264:in `catch'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:1324:in `transport_request'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:1301:in `request'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:1294:in `request'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:1292:in `request'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:83:in `response_for'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:39:in `request'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:634:in `raw_execute'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:612:in `execute'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:110:in `get'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/navigation.rb:14:in `to'
    from C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.10/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:77:in `goto'
    from (irb):3:in `evaluate'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1101:in `eval'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1501:in `loop'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1264:in `catch'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1264:in `catch'
    from C:\jruby-1.7.12\/bin/jirb_swing:53:in `(root)
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case this helped:

```
 TIMEOUT = 300 # set some value in seconds, f.ex. 300
 client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
 client.timeout = TIMEOUT # seconds – default is 60
 browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :http_client => client
```

I have found also:

```
require 'net/http' 
http = Net::HTTP.new(@host, @port)
http.read_timeout = 500
```

Please, check whether it helps in your case too.

Comment: Nope. It still results in a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Update your gems, specifically `gem update selenium-webdriver`